# How good is my shuffling algorithm?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, uniform-distribution

I've implemented [an array-shuffling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and I want to prove to myself that I didn't make any mistakes in the implementation.

Running it $n$ times on a small list, I can record the frequency with which each permutation occurs:

[image: chart]

I know that it *should* behave like a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)), but what statistical statements can I make about the data? How can I arrive at a $p$-value?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test.